# awk if not matched print "unknown", multiple matches

Tags: bash, awk, nmap

I am getting an nmap result and I am trying to process various (host up or down) results using awk.

I am passing an ip address and I am trying to get the following: status (up or down), host name, OS.
**GOAL: I need to have an access to every field to be able to update the database with its value. Also I am trying to accomplish that in as simple as possible way, maybe there is any way to save field in a variable so then I can use it, check if it's empty etc.?**

**More into details:**

1. if Host is down host_name="unknown", and OS="unknown"
2. if Host up grab the host_name and check OS -> two possibilities here, either /Running:/ or /OS guesses/ both of them will give us the OS, but we will have either one or another.

**Expected output of host that is up:**

```
                     $ip              $status     $host_name    $os
when host up:        134.99.120.2     host_up     HostName      Linux
when host down:      134.99.120.2     host_down   unknown       unknown
```

**I came up with this one liner here:**
`sudo nmap -O -R -p 22 -oN -T4  134.99.120.2  | awk '/down/{print$5}/Nmap scan report/{print$5}/Running:/{print$2}/OS guess/{print$4}'` 
But that does not provide any control over the output.

**Raw Outputs from nmap:**
**When Host up:**

```
 
> Starting Nmap 6.40 ( http://nmap.org ) at 2020-11-29 14:58 EST
> Nmap scan report for HostName (134.99.120.2) Host is up (0.00067s
> latency). PORT   STATE SERVICE 22/tcp open  ssh Warning: OSScan
> results may be unreliable because we could not find at least 1 open
> and 1 closed port Device type: general purpose Running: Linux OS CPE:
> xx:/o:xxx:xxxxxos:9.10 OS details: Linux Network Distance: 7 hops OS
> detection performed. Please report any incorrect results at
> http://nmap.org/submit/ . Nmap done: 1 IP address (1 host up) scanned
> in 2.58 seconds
```

**When host down:**

```
> Starting Nmap 6.40 ( http://nmap.org ) at 2020-11-29 15:00 EST
> Note: Host seems down. If it is really up, but blocking our ping
> probes, try -Pn Nmap done: 1 IP address (0 hosts up) scanned in 3.64
> seconds
```

Comment: Remove option `-T4`?

Comment: The hostname in your example is not in the output of nmap?

Comment: @Raman Sailopal it's in the host that is up: "> Nmap scan report for HostName "

Comment: @Cyrus option -T4 of nmap seem not to have anything to do with the data processing rather with intensity of the scan.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**NOTE** Looks like Raman was a bit faster on the 'Post Your Answer' button ...

Assumptions:

- `nmap` output will always be like one of the two examples provided by OP
- `nmap` output will always have the `Hostname` and `OS` name in the same fields (ie, don't have to worry about `nmap` wrapping lines at different words due to variable lengths of data)
- while the OP shows `OS guess` in their sample `awk`, the sample `nmap` data shows `OS details` (answer - below - is based on `OS details`; OP can modify per what their `nmap` call actually returns)
- `nmap` data does in fact include a `>` in the first column of every line of output (as displayed in OPs sample inputs); this means OPs `awk` field references may need to shift +/- accordingly (OP can adjust answer - below - based on whether or not a line starts with `>`)

Sample inputs (in lieu of running `nmap` on my host):

```
$ cat nmap.up.dat
> Starting Nmap 6.40 ( http://nmap.org ) at 2020-11-29 14:58 EST
> Nmap scan report for HostName (134.99.120.2) Host is up (0.00067s
> latency). PORT   STATE SERVICE 22/tcp open  ssh Warning: OSScan
> results may be unreliable because we could not find at least 1 open
> and 1 closed port Device type: general purpose Running: Linux OS CPE:
> xx:/o:xxx:xxxxxos:9.10 OS details: Linux Network Distance: 7 hops OS
> detection performed. Please report any incorrect results at
> http://nmap.org/submit/ . Nmap done: 1 IP address (1 host up) scanned
> in 2.58 seconds

$ cat nmap.down.dat
> Starting Nmap 6.40 ( http://nmap.org ) at 2020-11-29 15:00 EST
> Note: Host seems down. If it is really up, but blocking our ping
> probes, try -Pn Nmap done: 1 IP address (0 hosts up) scanned in 3.64
> seconds
```

One `awk` solution, though I'm assuming OP won't actually have 2 sets of `nmap` output for a single ip address (???) ...

```
ipaddr='134.99.120.2'

awk -v ip="${ipaddr}" '                                # pass ip addr in as awk variable "ip"
FNR==1            { hstat="host_up"                    # reset defaults for status ...
                    hname=hos="unknown"                # hostname and host OS
                  }
/down/            { hstat="host_down" ; next }         # reset status
/scan report for/ { hname=$6          ; next }         # reset hostname
/OS details/      { hos=$5            ; next }         # reset host OS

ENDFILE           { fmt="%-18s%-12s%-15s%s\n"          # re-usable format
                    if ( NR==FNR )                     # for first file print a header:
                       { printf fmt, "$ip", "$status", "$host_name", "$os" }

                    printf fmt, ip, hstat, hname, hos  # otherwise print results
                  }
' nmap.up.dat nmap.down.dat
```

**NOTE**: `ENDFILE` requires `GNU awk` (per Ed Morton's comment)

The above generates:

```
$ip               $status     $host_name     $os
134.99.120.2      host_up     HostName       Linux
134.99.120.2      host_down   unknown        unknown
```

Comment: "One awk solution, though I'm assuming OP won't actually have 2 sets of nmap output for a single ip address (???) ..."     -  that's correct. This is an awesome solution!

Comment: You should mention that requires GNU awk for ENDFILE.

Answer (score 2):

You can actually format the data as required by setting the extracted data as variables within awk and then printing them in an END block and so:

```
 sudo nmap -O -R -p 22 -oN -T4  134.99.120.2  | awk -v ip="134.99.120.2" '

 /Host is up/ { 
                 status="host_up" 
              } 
 /Host seems down/ { 
                 status="host_down" 
              } 
 /Nmap scan report/ { 
                 hstname=$5 
              } 
 /Running:/ { 
                 os=$2 
            } 
 /OS guess/ { 
                 os=$4 
            } 
        END { 
                 !os?os="unknown":os=os;
                 !hstname?hstname="unknown":hstname=hstname;
                 printf "%s\t%s\t%s\t%s\n",ip,status,hstname,os 
             }'
```

One liner:

```
sudo nmap -O -R -p 22 -oN -T4  134.99.120.2 | awk -v ip="134.99.120.2" '/Host is up/ { status="host_up" } /Host seems down/ { status="host_down" } /Nmap scan report/ { hstname=$5 } /Running:/ { os=$2 } /OS guess/ { os=$4 } END { !os?os="unknown":os=os;!hstname?hstname="unknown":hstname=hstname;printf "%s\t%s\t%s\t%s\n",ip,status,hstname,os }'
```

Pass the variable ip into awk with -F and then set the os, hstname and status based on the  searched text. In the end block, check to see if hstname and os variables exist. If they don't exist, set the variables to unknown, otherwise set them to what they already are. Finally print the variables in the format required.

Comment: Fantastic, This works perfectly and as expected. Thank you @Raman Sailopal

Comment: No worries. A like is always welcome also ;@)

Answer (score 1):

Decided to take a swipe at a (simple) token analyzer that eliminates the need for hard coded field references in `awk`, but still assumes the textual output from `nmap` is as displayed in the OPs sample outputs.

Sample inputs (in lieu of running `nmap` on my host):

```
$ cat nmap.up.dat
> Starting Nmap 6.40 ( http://nmap.org ) at 2020-11-29 14:58 EST
> Nmap scan report for HostName (134.99.120.2) Host is up (0.00067s
> latency). PORT   STATE SERVICE 22/tcp open  ssh Warning: OSScan
> results may be unreliable because we could not find at least 1 open
> and 1 closed port Device type: general purpose Running: Linux OS CPE:
> xx:/o:xxx:xxxxxos:9.10 OS details: Linux Network Distance: 7 hops OS
> detection performed. Please report any incorrect results at
> http://nmap.org/submit/ . Nmap done: 1 IP address (1 host up) scanned
> in 2.58 seconds

$ cat nmap.down.dat
> Starting Nmap 6.40 ( http://nmap.org ) at 2020-11-29 15:00 EST
> Note: Host seems down. If it is really up, but blocking our ping
> probes, try -Pn Nmap done: 1 IP address (0 hosts up) scanned in 3.64
> seconds
```

One `awk` idea for a token analyzer:

```
ipaddr='134.99.120.2'

awk -v ip="${ipaddr}" '                             # pass ip addr in as awk variable "ip"
FNR==1  { hstat="host_up"                           # reset defaults for status ...
          hname=hos="unknown"                       # hostname and host OS
          prev=""                                   # clear our "prev"ious token
        }

        { for ( i=1 ; i<=NF ; i++ )                 # process each field
              { token=$(i)                          # make note of current token aka field
                if ( token == ">" ) continue        # ignore the ">" in the first column

                # if our "prev"ious token matches any of the case statements then
                # update our variables according to the current token

                switch (prev) {
                    case "scan"           : if ( token == "report") { prev=prev" "token } ; break
                    case "scan report"    : if ( token == "for"   ) { prev=prev" "token } ; break
                    case "scan report for": hname=token             ; prev=token          ; break

                    case "down."          : hstat="host_down"       ; prev=token          ; break
                    case "Running:"       : hos=token               ; prev=token          ; break
                    default               : prev=token                                    ; break
                }
              }
        }
ENDFILE { fmt="%-18s%-12s%-15s%s\n"                 # re-usable format
          if ( NR==FNR )                            # for first file print a header:
             { printf fmt, "$ip", "$status", "$host_name", "$os" }

          printf fmt, ip, hstat, hname, hos         # otherwise print results
        }

' nmap.up.dat nmap.down.dat
```

**NOTE**: ENDFILE requires GNU awk

This above generates:

```
$ip               $status     $host_name     $os
134.99.120.2      host_up     HostName       Linux
134.99.120.2      host_down   unknown        unknown
```